# Flash Escape Game Item

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a flash game that requires picking up items. The item disappears when you click on it, but it reappears when you leave the room and come back. I tried setting a variable in the function and then using an if statement in the main code but that didn't work because the variable is local. And if I declare the variable outside the function, it reinitializes when you enter the frame(return to the room). A global variable should solve this problem. I know everyone says they're bad to use but I'm just looking for a solution.

```
//Pick up key
key_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, getKey);

function getKey(Event: MouseEvent):void{
    var gotKey:Boolean = true;
}


if(gotKey == true){
    key_btn.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: please add part of your code or your previous attempts... you can edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I suggest you to keep all codes in one frame and use movieclips to represent different rooms.

You can add a layer for the global vars and expand it, such as this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I added a layer for global variables, but everything else was set up the way you. I put the variable in the top layer but I have the same problem. The key doesn't stay invisible when you return to the room.

Comment: Note that you should not return to the frame that contains `var gotKey:Boolean = false;`(first frame), This approach works for me.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: @CoolestDudeOne, If this answer helped you, tick to the left of the answer to accept it!